# Widget update function not saving values

Tags: plugin-development, functions, widgets

Hello WordPress Answers!

I'm having trouble with the widget `update` function saving values correctly, but first let me explain the situation.

I'm writing a simple news ticker widget plugin, which filters the posts displayed by post type with check boxes in the widget settings form. To generate the check boxes I'm using a `foreach` loop over the available post types.

However, the widget update function isn't saving the post type values. I confirmed this by doing a `print_r` in the form function (values exist) and again in the widget function (values do not exist).

Here is my code:

```
class ami_newsticker_widget extends WP_Widget {

// process the widget
function ami_newsticker_widget () {

    $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'ticketcontainer',
        'description' => 'Display a scrolling newsticker'
    );
    $this->WP_Widget( 'ami_newsticker_widget', 'AMI News Ticker Widget', $widget_ops );
}

// build the widget settings form
function form( $instance ) {
    $defaults   = array( 'num_posts' => 5 );
    $instance   = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
    $num_posts  = $instance['num_posts'];

foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type ) {
  $instance['post_types'] .= $post_type . ',';
}
$post_types = $instance['post_types'];
    //echo '<pre>';
//print_r($instance);
    //echo '</pre>';

    ?>

        <p>Number of posts to show: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'num_posts' ); ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $num_posts ); ?>" /></p>
        <p>Filter by Post Type: <ul>
        <?php foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type ) { ?>
            <li><input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( $post_type ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $this->get_field_name( $post_type ) ); ?> /><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( $post_type ); ?>" /><?php echo $post_type; ?></label></li>
        <?php
       } ?>
        </ul></p>

    <?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($instance);
echo '</pre>';
}

// save the widget settings
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['num_posts'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['num_posts'] );
$instance['post_types'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['post_types'] );

    return $instance;
}

// display the widget
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        global $wpdb;
        extract( $args );

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($instance);
  echo '</pre>';

        // load the widget settings
  //foreach ( $instance['post_types'] as $post_type ) {
    //if ( $post_type == 'on' ) {
      //$checked .= $instance['post_types'][$post_type] . ' ,';
    //}
  //}
  //echo $checked;

        // get and clean the db data
        $num_posts = intval( absint( $instance['num_posts'] ) );
        $sql = "SELECT post_title, guid
                        FROM {$wpdb->posts}
                        WHERE post_status = 'publish'
                        ORDER BY post_date DESC
                        LIMIT {$num_posts}";

        $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

        // print the widget
        echo $before_widget;
        echo '<ul id="webticker">';

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $result->guid . '">' . $result->post_title . '</a></li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo $after_widget;
}
```

}

It seems like there is something obvious that I'm missing, but I've been banging my head against a wall on this!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume this is a class that extends `WP_Widget`? What is the generated output of the form? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Yes, sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: bronze, *much better* is to [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/74346/edit) the Question and include all the relevant code. Oh, yes, welcome to WPSE!

Comment: brasofilo, Got it. Updated my code to include the entire widget class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took a bit to sort out. :)

You are trying to use `$instance['post_types']` in your `update()` function but are not setting that value at all in the form. I altered a couple of things so that the two match up.

Leaving your form (mostly) as it is, your `update()` needs to be...

```
// save the widget settings
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['num_posts'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['num_posts'] );
    // start of the change
    foreach (get_post_types() as $post_type) {
      $instance[$post_type] = $new_instance[$post_type];
    }
    // end of the change
    return $instance;
}
```

Now, that will get things to save but it won't look like it because your [`checked()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) is a little off, so your `form()` needs to be altered just a little bit. Change the code for the list items to...

```
<input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( $post_type ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php echo checked( $instance[$post_type] ,'on' ); ?> />
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( $post_type ); ?>" /><?php echo $post_type; ?></label>
```

Notice that the `checked()` function went from `checked( $this->get_field_name( $post_type ) );` to `checked( $instance[$post_type] ,'on' );` 'on' is the 'true' value.

You were trying to use a 'post_types' array but that didn't match what was in the form, so I altered the update function to match the form. You could do it the other way around and alter the form to create an array. I think my way is easier though.

Some bits of the code you really don't need, like...

```
foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type ) {
   $instance['post_types'][$post_type] = '';
}
```

And that will cause trouble if you try to use the 'post_types' array. It will overwrite that variable every time.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so so much! It all makes sense now... :)

Comment: Brilliant answer!